# Calling 'git lfs pull' in a CI/CD pipeline

Tags: python, git, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, git-lfs

I am using a CI/CD pipeline in combination with [`git-lfs`](https://git-lfs.github.com/). At the beginning of my script, I want to load a pickle file (see code further below) that is stored via LFS. My code runs fine on the local machine, but in the pipeline I get the following error:

> _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'v'

[It](https://github.com/svip-lab/PPGNet/issues/2) [seems](https://github.com/DwangoMediaVillage/3dpose_gan/issues/1) [that](https://github.com/ijmarshall/robotreviewer/issues/18) this error is caused by the LFS file not being fetched and can be resolved with a simple `git lfs pull` command.

The question now is, how can I call `git lfs pull` in the pipeline? I naively tried adding it in the `.yml` file where I call my python scripts too, but that didn't work. I'm sorry if is this question is a bit stupid, I'm a bit outside of my normal field here.

EDIT with some details on when the error occurs and the CI/CD used:

These are the lines that cause the error to occur:

```py
open("path_to_file/file", 'rb')
data = pickle.load(f)
```

I am using a Gitlab CI/CD and the `.yml` file defining the workflow is the following:

```yaml
before_script:
    - rm -rf "*-env"; python3.8 -m venv ${CI_JOB_ID}-env
    - ${CI_JOB_ID}-env/bin/pip3 install -U pip

after_script:
    - rm -rf ${CI_JOB_ID}-env

stages:
    - calculations

CalcStrategicValues:
    stage: calculations
    only:
        - calculate
    script:
        - ${CI_JOB_ID}-env/bin/pip3 install -r requirements.txt
        # - ${CI_JOB_ID}-env/git lfs pull           <- my attempt at solving the problem
        - ${CI_JOB_ID}-env/bin/python3 calculate.py
    allow_failure: false
    artifacts:
        name: results
        when: always
        paths:
            - output/
```

Comment: What tool are you using for your pipeline?  Can you include the relevant portions as  a code block so that we can offer advice?

Comment: @bk2204 I'm, unfortunately, not sure what you mean, but the error occurs when calling the lines `f = open("path_to_file/file", 'rb')` and then `data = pickle.load(f)`, where file is an lfs-file.

Comment: You said you're using a CI/CD pipeline for your code.  Is that GitHub Actions?  Is it something else?  Edit your questions to show us the GitHub Actions workflow file or the other CI/CD pipeline description as a code block.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I added it to the original question. I hope this contains all the required information.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as I dont see any other answers. I had the same issue and I added the below lines inside the shell script I was using

```
git install lfs
git lfs pull
```

Here is the .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - pricing_deploy

.pdeploy: &pdeploy
    script:
    - chmod +x pdeploy.sh
    - ./pdeploy.sh $SERVER_NAME

deploy_pricing_files:
  stage: pricing_deploy
  variables:
    SERVER_NAME: $SERVER_BRM25
  <<: *pdeploy
```

and I added the lfs install and pull inside the pdeploy.sh script

Not sure if its fixed with the latest runners : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4742

Anyway hope this is useful to somebody